# Consulta sobre input value en javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, javascript-import

estoy en la incognita de un problemilla, estoy aprendiendo javascript y me encuentro con que quiero hacer que el valor de un input se cambie, mediante un evento click a un boton, me renderiza perfecto 1 vez , pero cuando cambio el valor nuevamente , no me renderiza el nuevo valor.

```
function porcentaje (x,y){

    return x +(y*x/100)

}
```

USO DE LA FUNCION PARA SACAR PORCENTAJE CON EL BOTON

```
var calculate = document.querySelector('#calculate');

var priceCost = document.querySelector('#priceCost').value;

var percentageValue = document.querySelector('#percentage').value;

var priceSale = document.querySelector('#priceSale');

calculate.addEventListener('click',function(e){

        e.preventDefault()

        var resultado = porcentaje(parseInt(priceCost),parseInt(percentageValue))

        priceSale.value = resultado

    })
```

HTML

```
<label for="priceCost">Precio de costo</label>
<input type="number" name="priceCost" id="priceCost">

<label for="percentage">Porcentaje de venta</label>
<input type="number" name="percentage" id="percentage">

<label for="priceSale">Precio de venta</label>
<input type="number" name="priceSale" id="priceSale">

<button type="submit" id="calculate">Calcular</button>
```

Como les decia, al hacer click en el boton me saca el resultado del porcentaje, y me lo muestra en el input, pero al querer volver a pasarle otro porcentaje y hago click nuevamente en el boton con otro valor de porcentaje en el input, me queda siempre el primer resultado, "dato, cuando refresco la web y le vuelvo a dar click al boton, me genera el nuevo porcentaje con el valor nuevo.", Gracias a todos por su aporte! y a seguir aprendiendo!!

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar tu HTML por favor?

Comment: Hola!, gracias por tu tiempo!, ahi lo agregue. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Estas obteniendo los valores fuera del evento clic, y va a conservar el valor inicial, para resolverlo lleva todos los `document.querySelector` dentro de tu callback

Comment: @AníbalJorquera ¡funciona!, me estaba volviendo loco, ¡¡muchas gracias!!!, aun soy nuevo en esto y me encanta. Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás definiendo *priceCost* y *percentageValue* con el valor de los campos y no se actualizan posteriormente.

```
var priceCost = document.querySelector('#priceCost').value;
```

Lo más adecuado es definir sin `.value` para tomar el campo y, cuando realices los cálculos lo agregas.

```js
var calculate = document.querySelector('#calculate');
// Sin .value, para hacer referencia al campo y no al contenido
var priceCost = document.querySelector('#priceCost');
var percentageValue = document.querySelector('#percentage');
var priceSale = document.querySelector('#priceSale');

function porcentaje(costo, incremento) {
    return costo * ( 1 + (incremento / 100));
}
calculate.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Agregar .value a costo y porcentaje
    var resultado = porcentaje(parseInt(priceCost.value), parseInt(percentageValue.value));
    priceSale.value = resultado;
});
```

```html
<label for="priceCost">Precio de costo</label>
<input type="number" name="priceCost" id="priceCost">

<label for="percentage">Porcentaje de venta</label>
<input type="number" name="percentage" id="percentage">

<label for="priceSale">Precio de venta</label>
<input type="number" name="priceSale" id="priceSale">

<button type="submit" id="calculate">Calcular</button>
```

Comment: Genial!!. muchas gracias, voy a probar tambien esta manera!.